# Cups confuses orientation on Zebra label printer

Tags: printing

I'm having a slight issue.
First of all I made custom PPD file to suppport my label sizes. I'm using 40x25mm labels. Unfortunately there seems to be an issue of "portrait" orientation with longer width than height. When i print with portrait orientation selected in Printing Options my labels are centered but clipped in width to 25mm. When I print with landscape orientation whole label seems to print but is offset towards middle of label, as if origin of print is moved close to center i.e for rotated print.

The changes that i made to ZEBRAEP2.PPD aside from removing translations to make work easier on myself are:

```
*OpenUI *PageSize/Media Size: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *PageSize
*DefaultPageSize: w118h73
*PageSize w118h73/25.05x39.86mmRotated: "<</PageSize[118 73]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *PageSize

*OpenUI *PageRegion/Media Size: PickOne
*OrderDependency: 10 AnySetup *PageRegion
*DefaultPageRegion: w118h73
*PageRegion w118h73/25.05x39.86mmRotated: "<</PageSize[118 73]/ImagingBBox null>>setpagedevice"
*CloseUI: *PageRegion

*DefaultImageableArea: w118h73
*ImageableArea w118h73/25.05x39.86mmRotated: "0 0 118.77 73.135"

*DefaultPaperDimension: w118h73
*PaperDimension w118h73/25.05x39.86mmRotated: "118.77 73.135"
```

File checks out fine with `cupstestppd`, aside from size name not meeting Adobe standard for some reason.

It would be probably important to add that I'm using 22.04, and trying to work with Zebra TLP2824 label printer. I tried every dimension and orientation combination that i could but to no avail. Trying entering dimensions as for 25x40 makes things even worse aside from advancing paper two labels. On every since 20.04 it printed fine with command `lpr -o orientation-requested=6 -P TLP2824 label.pdf`, and i'm absolutely positive that label in PDF is 40x25mm.

What am i doing wrong? How can it be communicated in ppd file that landscape, 40x25 is actually a default orientation, or how can i override cropping of image since printer does good job cropping image outside of work area by itself?

Comment: perhaps try gLabels downloadable from ubuntu software?

Comment: gLabels looks good but doesn't fix my issue unfortunately, as it's issue with printing.

Comment: I have something similar happening with paper size 215.9x101.6mm (Width > Height) on RHEL8/CUPS-2.2.6. It used to work on RHEL5/CUPS-1.3.7. My setup is Java-Application ---> RHEL Print Server/CUPS ---> Windows-10 Shared Printer / SMB ---> Printer (Epson LQ-2190).  For some reason, the application printout comes in Landscape mode (rotated 90 degrees anti-clockwise) off to the right from center. Test prints issued from CUPS have same orientation issue while Test prints issued from Workstation to which Printer is connected have correct orientation.

Comment: I tried setting Orientation to Portrait and Landscape in Printer preferences on Windows-10 Workstation to which the printer is attached, but it didn't make a difference for Test prints issued from CUPS. I have now opened a case with RedHat Support; I suspect the issue with the printer's Linux driver or CUPS 2.x.